# Php - Password hashing

Tags: php, hash

I've made this password class as you can see below:

```
<?php

namespace lib\Api;

class Password{

    private $password;
    private $salt;
    private $hash;

    public function __construct($password,$salt = ""){
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->salt = $salt;
        $this->generateHash($this->password,$this->salt);
    }
    public function generateHash($password,$salt = ""){
        $this->hash = hash('sha256',$password.$salt);
        return $this->hash;
    }
    public function get(){
        return $this->hash;
    }
    public function equals($password){
        if($this->hash == $password){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

So i use this to register a user in a `user.php` file/class

```
$this->password = (new Password($password,$this->getSalt()))->get();
```

, i also use this too again check this in a `login.php` file/class

```
if((new Password($this->password,$salt))->equals($password)){
    return true;
}
return false;
```

. Now i know that if you hash something that it depends in wich file it is, how it hashes the value. In this partical case it confuses me very much, as i both officialy hash it in the `password.php` file/class. How does this work and how can i solve it easily and nicely?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Federico Hopefully it is more clear now?

Comment: I don't get this part *"...that it depends in wich file it is, how it hashes the value. In this partical case it confuses me very much..."*. Can you paraphrase it, please?

Comment: So, if you hash a string in a certain file, it will be different if you execute that same hash in a different file

Comment: Stop. Delete your code. Implement with [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), which use the industry-standard and much more secure `bcrypt` algorithm.

Comment: Encryption/Hashes are deterministic, for any string, sha256(string) will always result the same hash, no matter which file it was executed in

Comment: Oh really? I have heard different, and I believe had something with it already

Comment: I think you're confusing over what's called a `checksum`, which is a hash of  the contents of a file used to validate that a file you've been given hasn't been altered in anyway.  But even so, the checksum is deterministic based on the file contents.  If it wasn't, like any other hash, then it would be completely pointless to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you're asking, but I bet you want to hash the value of $password before you check it's equality.

```
<?php

namespace lib\Api;

class Password{

    private $password;
    private $salt;
    private $hash;

    public function __construct($password,$salt = ""){
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->salt = $salt;
        $this->hash = $this->generateHash($this->password);
    }
    public function generateHash($password){
        return hash('sha256',$password.$this->salt);
    }
    public function get(){
        return $this->hash;
    }
    public function equals($password){
        if($this->hash == $this->generateHash($password){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i do that. Although the password equals ( I check that from the user registration etc) the hash doesn't equal. So that has something to do that it is in a different file.

Comment: You also are using a local $salt and the attribute $this->salt inconsistently, one sec and I'll post code that I think is more correct.

Comment: Yes, saw that as you mentioned it. Although this does not matter anything for the problem.. still thank you